# Keras: Get the first n layers

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am loading an autoencoder from a saved file by doing the following, with the shown structure:

```
autoencoder = load_model("autoencoder_mse1.h5")
autoencoder.summary()
>>> ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)             (None, 19)            0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_43 (Dense)                 (None, 16)            320         input_8[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_44 (Dense)                 (None, 16)            272         dense_43[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_45 (Dense)                 (None, 2)             34          dense_44[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_46 (Dense)                 (None, 16)            48          dense_45[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_47 (Dense)                 (None, 16)            272         dense_46[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_48 (Dense)                 (None, 19)            323         dense_47[0][0]                   
====================================================================================================
Total params: 1269
__________________
```

The first four layers, including the `InputLayer`, constitute the encoder part. I was wondering if there was a quick way of grabbing those four layers. So far the only possible solutions I've come across is:

```
encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(Dense(16, 19, weights=autoencoder.layers[1].get_weights()))
```

^ and do this manually for two more layers. I'm hoping that there is a way to extract the first four layers in a more efficient way. Especially since the `.summary()` method spits out the layer summaries.

**edit 1 (possible solution)**:
I've arrived at the following solution, but I'm hoping for something a bit more efficient (less code).

```
encoder = Sequential()
for i,l in enumerate(autoencoder.layers[1:]):
    if i==0:
        encoder.add(Dense(input_dim=data.shape[1],output_dim=l.output_dim,
                          activation="relu",weights=l.get_weights()))
    else:
        encoder.add(Dense(output_dim=l.output_dim,activation="relu",weights=l.get_weights()))
    if l.output_dim == 2:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this and let me know if it worked:

```
# TO get first four layers
model.layers[0:3]
#To get the input shape
model.layers[layer_of_interest_index].input_shape
#To get the input shape
model.layers[layer_of_interest_index].output_shape
# TO get weights matrices
model.layers[layer_of_interest_index].get_weights()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to get at, but this answer, should be a comment. It doesn't answer my question directly. I can get the weights this method, but I would still need to know the dimensions of the weights and the type of layer to stack apriori.